# Calulating the hours and minutes between clock in and clock out timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I'm developing a timesheet clocking system. Users log their date and time when they clock into a building and offcourse when they clock out of a building.

The trick is that I need to calculate the current total IN time in hours and minutes.

so, you have this scenario:

> user clock IN at 08:00
>  user clock OUT at 12:00
>   = 4 hours
>  user clock IN at 12:30
>  user clock OU at 13:30
>   =1 hour
>
> user clock IN at 16:00
>  user clock OUT at 18:30 
>   = 2hours and 30 minutes.

Now, I know that MySQL has a `HOUR(TIMEDIFF(t2,t1)) AS hour, MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(t2,t1)) AS minute` function but not sure how to workout the intervals between each IN-OUT combination and ignoring the OUt-IN so that I get a TOTAL for ONLY time spend ON Site or IN the building.

So in other words NOT from the first IN and last OUT.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : Please try the below link for your required scenario :

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47cb0/4)**

-- Below code is to be used when IN & OUT are in the same row --

You can use below query to calculate data in hours :

```
select EMP ,sum(datediff(hour,cast([in] as datetime)
       ,cast([out] as datetime)) ) 
from table1
GROUP BY EMP
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8448/3)**

Comment: thank you for the input I appreciate it. However, my table is structure as follows: ID | date_stamp | user_id | action. so typical you can imagine the following record row : 12 | 2013-10-04 08:00:00 | IN and then on the NEXT row the corresponding OUT. So I dont have a IN and OUT column on the same row. :) This is what makes it tricky.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2002-05-01','2001-01-01');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff